# how to view open chrome tabs from web?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, tabs

I like to use Chrome on my desktop pc. I don't like it in my laptop and don't have Chrome on my phone. I don't sync Chrome on my work pc. Sometimes I want to open page on my phone or work pc. This page is already opened on my home desktop and settings from desktop are synced. How can I see list of opened tabs in my home desktop? Some web page with list of opened tabs would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome browser, go to History. You will see a list of synced devices with open tabs at the top of the screen.

Comment: Do you mean History inside Chrome browser?

Comment: I don't have Chrome browser on my phone and my pc on work doesn't sync. I thought it clear from my question...

Comment: There is no way to see your open tab without using sync. Sorry, your question is not clear to me.